# Subscript letters in ggplot axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to work out how to have subscript letters in an axis label.

```
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(y=expression(Blah[1]))

dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(y=expression(Blah[1d]))
```

The first example works as it's just a number, as soon as you have a character in the square brackets, it fails. Blah[subscript(1d)] is essentially what I need, but I can't work out how to get it to let me have letters in subscript. I have tried variations, including `paste()`.

The following examples provide strange behavior:

```
labs(y=expression(Blah[12])) # this works
labs(y=expression(Blah[d])) # this works
labs(y=expression(Blah[d1])) # this works
labs(y=expression(Blah[1d])) # this fails
```

Thoughts?

Comment: TL;DNR version:  `y=expression(Blah[1*d])`  Need a non-space R syntax operator which is `*`.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The reason the last one fails is that the arguments to `expression` get run through the R parser and an error is returned when they fail the test of whether they could possibly be correct R syntax. The string or token `1d` is not a valid R token (or symbol). It would be possible to either break it into valid R tokens and "connect" with non-space operators,  backtick it , or use ordinary quotes. I think either is a better way than using `paste`:

```
 ggplot(dat, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
     geom_point() +
     labs(y=expression(Blah[1*d]))
 ggplot(dat, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
     geom_point() +
     labs(y=expression(Blah["1d"]))
```

Tokens (or "names" or "symbols") in R are not supposed to start with digits. So you get around that limitation by either quoting or by separating `1` and `d` by a non-space separator, the `*` operator. That "joins" or "ligates" a pure numeric literal with a legal R symbol or token.

To get a percent sign unsubscripted just:

```
 ggplot(dat, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(y=expression(Blah[1*d]*"%"))
```

To put parens around the pct-sign:

```
expression(Blah[1*d]*"(%)")
```

The `%` character has special meaning in R parsing, since it signifies the beginning of a user defined infix operator. So using it as a literal requires that it be quoted. The same reasoning requires that "for" and "in" be quoted, because they are in the "reserved words" group for R. There are other reserved words, (but `for` and `in` are the ones that trip me up most often.) Type:

```
 ?Reserved
```

And another "trick" is to use quotation marks around digits within `italic()`if you need them italicized. Unquoted digits do not get italicized inside that function.

Caveats: `paste` is a plotmath function **except**  it has different semantics than the `base::paste function`. In particular, it has no 'sep' argument. So you can never get a space between the printed arguments and if you try to put in a non-space item, a single instance will appear after all the other arguments labeled as `sep=" "`.

`paste0` is not a plotmath function and so will not get interpreted but rather will appear "unprocessed" with its unprocessed arguments inside parentheses.

Comment: Thanks DWin, didn't know it was called a token. While it wasn't in the question (but was in my answer), can you get (%) after the subscript without paste?

Comment: Special thanks for non-space separator, was looking for it for some time already.

Comment: It has always been surprising to me that the `?plotmath` page does not do a better job of describing the syntactic requirements. It just says that it's just like regular R, but they really ought to add a small paragraph that expands on that.

Answer (score 16):

Okay. I swear I didn't post this just to answer it myself, despite how quickly I got it (always the way when you ask a question!)

Here it is:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(y=expression(Blah[1][d]))
```

Thought it best to post the answer rather than remove the question as it may help someone else one day.

'Blahs' aside, what I actually wanted was `expression(paste("Hb", A[1][c]," (%)",sep=""))`

Why `paste0()` doesn't work here is beyond me.

Comment: `paste0` is not a plotmath function. `paste` is a plotmath function except that it has different semantics than the `base::paste` function. In particular it has no 'sep' argument.

Comment: And in R expressions you need to quoted any special characters like `%` or reserved words like "in"