# How to write cm yr^-1 in axis label or xlab R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, axis, exponential

How can I write `cm yr^-1` in axis label or `xlab` R using `ggplot2` ?

I've tried:

```
xlab("Predicted dbh annual increment\n(cm yr^{-1})")
```

but failed.

Thanks for your help.

Abd Rahman

Comment: You could try something like the following `xlab(bquote("Predicted dbh annual increment (cm" ~yr^{-1}~ ")"))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subscript letters in ggplot axis label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334759/subscript-letters-in-ggplot-axis-label)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Unicode symbol of the minus and just do copy and paste: "⁻¹"

Or you can take a look at the shortcuts for all systems. For Linux it would be:
"Ctrl+Shift+U"+"207b" for the minus and
"circumflex"+"1" for the superscript one