# Why this R ggplot subscript is not working?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

Code where trying to apply `g + labs(y=expression(N_{s}))` with the following error which does not make sense

```
g <- ggplot(datm, aes(variable, value, fill=gender)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge()) + facet_grid(male.Nij ~ group) + xlab("Association type") + ggtitle("View")
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/17335258/54964
g + labs( y=expression(N_{s}) )
```

I get

```
Error: unexpected '{' in "g + labs( y=expression(N_{"
Execution halted
```

R: 3.3.2 backports
OS: Debian 8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it it not `{}`

```
# if you want to use sbuscript, use []
p + labs( y=expression(N[s]) )
# or as is
p + labs( y=expression(N_~'{s}') )
```