# How to have many subscripts in this R read.csv for axis labels?

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, axis-labels, subscript

Data code

```
fem <- read.csv( text=
"female Bij,B11,B22,B33,B44,B21,B31,B32,B123
Sinus,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,12.0,0.0")
```

I would like to have subscripts instead like `expression(B[11])` so my pseudocode is

```
text=  
paste0("female ", expression(B[ij]), expression(B[11]), ..., expression(B[123]))  
Sinus,1.0,0.0,...")
```

Maybe, this can be done with a function better or later directly with `ggplot2`. 
I plot the data eventually as where the data `B11,...,B123` is in `female.Bij`

```
library("ggplot2")
g <- ggplot(datm, aes(variable, value, fill=gender)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge()) + facet_grid(female.Bij ~ group) + xlab("Type") 
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/17335258/54964
g + labs( y="Counts")
```

### Testing rawr's answer

Before the operation and after the operation, my data set

```
[1] "hello ==="
           male.Bij     gender             group              variable 
 Arr/AHB       :32   Length:128         Length:128         B11    :16  
 Digoxin arr   :32   Class :character   Class :character   B22    :16  
 Furosemide arr:32   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   B33    :16  
 Sinus         :32                                         B44    :16  
                                                           B21    :16  
                                                           B31    :16  
                                                           (Other):32  
     value                  male.Nij 
 Min.   : 0.000   Sinus         :32  
 1st Qu.: 0.000   Arr/AHB       :32  
 Median : 0.000   Digoxin arr   :32  
 Mean   : 1.407   Furosemide arr:32  
 3rd Qu.: 0.850                      
 Max.   :24.000                      

[1] "hello 2 ===="
           male.Bij     gender             group             variable        
 Arr/AHB       :32   Length:128         Length:128         Length:128        
 Digoxin arr   :32   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
 Furosemide arr:32   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
 Sinus         :32
```

Fig. 1 Output

[image]

Doing `g + scale_x_discrete(labels = parse(text = datm$variable))` gives me

[image]

### Testing rawr's answer with letters

Code relevant line

```
"female Bi,Bp,Br,Bt,B0,Bpr,Bpt,Brt,Bprt
```

Output

[image]

R: 3.3.2
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: a subscript in what? `paste0("female ", expression(B[ij]), ...)` is just going to be a character string. you can insert the brackets : `gsub('(?<=B)([^,]+)', '[\\1]', "female Bij,B11,B22,B33,B44,B21,B31,B32,B123", perl = TRUE)` but i'm not sure what you really want

Comment: sorry you don't need that regex in the update, please see my update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parse(text=...))` is an easy way to turn strings into expressions especially useful for plotting

```
parse(text = c('B[ij]', 'B[12]'))
# expression(B[ij], B[12])
```

In your example you can insert the brackets and use parse/text

```
fem <- read.csv( text=
                   "female Bij,B11,B22,B33,B44,B21,B31,B32,B123
                 Sinus,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,12.0,0.0",
                 strip.white = TRUE)

datm <- reshape2::melt(fem)
datm <- within(datm, {
  ## take the first character as the base and the remaining
  ## characters as the subscript (wrap in brackets)
  variable <- gsub('(.)(.+)', '\\1[\\2]', variable)
})

library("ggplot2")
g <- ggplot(datm, aes(variable, value, fill=female.Bij)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  # facet_grid(female.Bij ~ group) +
  xlab("Type") 

g + labs( y="Counts") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = parse(text = unique(datm$variable)),
                   breaks = unique(datm$variable))
```

[image]

Comment: @Masi are you doing the parse/text thing? the axis labels need to be an expression `+ scale_x_discrete(labels = parse(text = datm$variable))`

Comment: @Masi yes, try `scale_x_discrete(labels = parse(text = unique(datm$variable)), breaks = unique(datm$variable))` instead

Comment: Please, see the body. I will award you bounty on this if you can answer the new problem today. I have now letters which I would like to have in subscript. Is it possible with your approach?

Comment: @Masi it depends on how the format will be, is it one letter followed by the subscript? in that case just change the regex `variable <- gsub('(.)(.+)', '\\1[\\2]', variable)`

Comment: @Masi yes `(.)(.+)` will take one character for the base `(.)` and then one or more characters for the subscript `(.+)` and insert brackets around the `(.+)`

Comment: Thank you very much! Please, add it to your answer to help future readers. I will award you a bounty as soon as possible. You made my day!