# How to format x-axis tick label in sqrt(x) format?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I'm studying the example of coord_trans() of ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

set.seed(4747)    

df <- data.frame(a = abs(rnorm(26)),letters)
plot <- ggplot(df,aes(a,letters)) + geom_point()
plot + coord_trans(x = "log10")
plot + coord_trans(x = "sqrt")
```

I modified the code `plot + coord_trans(x = "log10")` as following and get what I expected:

```
plot + scale_x_log10(breaks=trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                     labels=trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))
```

I modified the code `plot + coord_trans(x = "sqrt")` as following and get a strange x-axis:

```
plot + scale_x_sqrt(breaks=trans_breaks("sqrt", function(x) sqrt(x)),
                   labels=trans_format("sqrt", math_format(.x^0.5)))
```

How could I fix the problem?

Comment: 1. `could not find function "trans_breaks"`; 2. how you define strange?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that "scales" packages used in this example.

Comment: Instead of `function(x) sqrt(x)` try `function(x) x^2`. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

I get why you said it was a strange / terrible axis. The documentation for `trans_breaks` even warns you about this in its first line:

> These often do not produce very attractive breaks.

To make it less unattractive, I would use `round(,2)` so my axis labels only have 2 decimal points instead of the default 8 or 9 - cluttering up the axis. Then I would set a sensible range, say in your case 0 to 5 (`c(0,5)`).

Finally, you can specify the number of ticks for your axis using `n` in the `trans_breaks` call.

So putting it together, here's how you can format your x-axis and its tick label in the `scale_x_sqrt(x)` format:

```
plot <- ggplot(df,aes(a,letters)) + geom_point()
plot + scale_x_sqrt(breaks=trans_breaks("sqrt", function(x) round(sqrt(x),2), n=5)(c(0, 5)))
```

Produces this:
[image]

The `c(0,5)` is passed to `pretty()`, a lesser-known Base R's function. From the documentation, `pretty` does the following:

> Compute a sequence of about n+1 equally spaced "round" values which cover the range of the values in x.

`pretty(c(0,5))` simply produces `[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5` in our case.

You can even fine-tune your axis by changing the parameters. Here the code uses 3 decimal points (`round(x,3)`) and we asked for 3 number of ticks `n=3`:

```
plot <- ggplot(df,aes(a,letters)) + geom_point()
plot + scale_x_sqrt(breaks=trans_breaks("sqrt", function(x) round(sqrt(x),3), n=3)(c(0, 5)))
```

Produces this: 
[image]

**EDIT** based on OP's additional comments:
To get round integer values, `floor()` or `round(x,0)` works, so the following code:

```
plot <- ggplot(df,aes(a,letters)) + geom_point()
plot + scale_x_sqrt(breaks=trans_breaks("sqrt", function(x) round(sqrt(x),0), n=5)(c(0, 5)))
```

Produces this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried the following code:                             
plot + scale_x_sqrt(breaks= trans_breaks("sqrt", function(x) round(sqrt(x),3), n=3)(c(0, 2)), labels=trans_format("sqrt", math_format(.x^2)))                                                                           how could I get the rounded labels of ticks? I've checked the functions of scales package, not found what I could use.

Comment: If you want rounded numbers, then instead of round with 3, round with 0: `+ scale_x_sqrt(breaks= trans_breaks("sqrt", function(x) round(sqrt(x),0), n=5)(c(0, 5))`. `floor()` also works. Did you try that?

Comment: I see what you meant, what if I need the expression like 12(2 is a superscript), not just 1(created by round() or floor())?

Comment: You would use `expression()` for that. I encourage to check out [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334759/subscript-letters-in-ggplot-axis-label). If you have a more specific use-case that the answer didn't sufficiently help, then feel free to post another SO question with that use-case and I can answer there. That also help keep this answer on-topic for others who land on this question. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I read the post you mentioned and the other related posts, they all discussed about the power of 10, not 2 I needed. I looked back the documentation of "math_format", and tried another way to solve my problem. This solution is not very good, but it achieved what I need. Here is my solution: options(digits=3); plot + scale_x_sqrt(breaks=
  trans_breaks("sqrt", function(x) round(sqrt(x),1), n=3)(c(0, 2)),
  labels=trans_format("sqrt", math_format(.x^2, format=signif)))