# Creating a box and whisker plot with ggplot() troubleshooting

Tags: r, ggplot2

UPDATED:

Data has now been updated to full chemistry values as opposed to mean values.

I am attempting to create a box and whisker plot in r, on a very small dataset. My data is not behaving itself or I am missing some glaringly obvious error.

```
  This is the code i have for making said plot
  library(ggplot2)
  Methanogenesis_Data=read.csv("CO2-CH4 Rates.csv")
  attach(Methanogenesis_Data)
  summary(Methanogenesis_Data)
  str(Methanogenesis_Data)

  boxplot(CH4rate~Patch+Temperature, data = Methanogenesis_Data, 
  xlab="Patch", ylab="CH4 Production")
  cols<-c("red", "blue")
```

From this small dataset.

```
  structure(list(Patch = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Gravel", "Macrophytes", 
  "Marginal"), class = "factor"), Temperature = structure(c(2L, 
  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Cold", 
  "Warm"), class = "factor"), CH4rate = c(0.001262595, 0.00138508, 
  0.001675944, 0.001592354, 0.002169233, 0.001772964, 0.002156633, 
  0.002864403, 0.002301383, 0.002561042, 0.005189598, 0.004557227, 
  0.008484851, 0.006867866, 0.007438633, 0.005405327, 0.006381582, 
  0.008860084, 0.007615417, 0.007705906, 0.009198508, 0.00705233, 
  0.007943024, 0.008319768, 0.010362114, 0.007822153, 0.010339339, 
  0.009252302, 0.008249555, 0.008197657), CO2rate = c(0.002274825, 
  0.002484866, 0.003020209, 0.00289133, 0.003927232, 0.003219346, 
  0.003922613, 0.005217026, 0.00418674, 0.00466427, 0.009427322, 
  0.008236453, 0.015339532, 0.012494729, 0.013531303, 0.009839847, 
  0.011624428, 0.016136746, 0.0138831, 0.014051034, 0.016753211, 
  0.012780956, 0.01445912, 0.01515584, 0.01883252, 0.014249452, 
  0.018849478, 0.016863299, 0.015045964, 0.014941168)), .Names = c("Patch", 
  "Temperature", "CH4rate", "CO2rate"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
  c(NA, 
  -30L))
```

The plot I get as output is good, however I would like the Variables on the X axis to simply display "Gravel" "Macrophytes" "Marginal" as opposed to each of those variables with Warm and Cold. Thanks for any assistance

THIS IS WHAT I AM TRYING TO ACHEIVE -----> [Exact Boxplot I want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtyRb.png)

Comment: If your dataset is as you have presented in your example I don't think you have enough data to plot a boxplot for each patch at each temperature. A box plot summarises a set of data it is not the correct format to plot one value for each data point. If you have summarised the data to calculate the mean you should use the orginal dataset to generate the boxplot.

Comment: @hisspott, thank you for your answer, you are correct, data is mean values. I'll attempt the same with the larger (original) data set.

Comment: @hisspott, UPDATED!, issue again but much smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your update with an example graph :

I have also included the formating for the legend position. If you want to edit the y axis label to include subscript I would suggest you read over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334759/subscript-letters-in-ggplot-axis-label). I have included a blank title for relabelling.

```
test <- structure(list(Patch = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Gravel", "Macrophytes", 
  "Marginal"), class = "factor"), Temperature = structure(c(2L, 
  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Cold", 
  "Warm"), class = "factor"), CH4rate = c(0.001262595, 0.00138508, 
  0.001675944, 0.001592354, 0.002169233, 0.001772964, 0.002156633, 
  0.002864403, 0.002301383, 0.002561042, 0.005189598, 0.004557227, 
  0.008484851, 0.006867866, 0.007438633, 0.005405327, 0.006381582, 
  0.008860084, 0.007615417, 0.007705906, 0.009198508, 0.00705233, 
  0.007943024, 0.008319768, 0.010362114, 0.007822153, 0.010339339, 
  0.009252302, 0.008249555, 0.008197657), CO2rate = c(0.002274825, 
  0.002484866, 0.003020209, 0.00289133, 0.003927232, 0.003219346, 
  0.003922613, 0.005217026, 0.00418674, 0.00466427, 0.009427322, 
  0.008236453, 0.015339532, 0.012494729, 0.013531303, 0.009839847, 
  0.011624428, 0.016136746, 0.0138831, 0.014051034, 0.016753211, 
  0.012780956, 0.01445912, 0.01515584, 0.01883252, 0.014249452, 
  0.018849478, 0.016863299, 0.015045964, 0.014941168)), .Names = c("Patch", 
  "Temperature", "CH4rate", "CO2rate"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
  c(NA, 
  -30L))
```

Now I will create two data sets one for each graph just for simplicity you could leave them combined and facet but for formatting purposes this might be easier.

```
CH4rate <- test %>%
  gather("id", "value", 3:4) %>%
  filter(id == "CH4rate")

CO2rate <- test %>%
  gather("id", "value", 3:4) %>%
  filter(id == "CO2rate")
```

First plot:

```
ggplot(CH4rate) +
  geom_boxplot(mapping = aes(x = Patch, y = value, fill=factor(Temperature, levels = c("Warm", "Cold")))) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.15, 0.9), panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50")) +
  labs(title = "Title of graph", x="Patch Type", y = "CH4rate") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("orange", "light blue")
                    , labels = c("Cold" = "Incubated at 10˙C", "Warm" = "Incubated at 26˙C"))
```

[image: First Plot: CH4rate]

Second plot:

```
ggplot(CO2rate) +
  geom_boxplot(mapping = aes(x = Patch, y = value, fill=factor(Temperature, levels = c("Warm", "Cold")))) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.15, 0.9), panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50")) +
  labs(title = "Title of graph", x="Patch Type", y = "CO2rate") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("orange", "light blue")
                    , labels = c("Cold" = "Incubated at 10˙C", "Warm" = "Incubated at 26˙C"))
```

[image: Second Plot: CO2rate]

Comment: Thank you, however, where is the temperature variable? Each plot should have 6 boxes 10*c and 26*c.

Comment: That was not specified in your original question but I have updated the answer.

Comment: See my answer above with image link included.