# Subscripting letters in complex ggplot2 title

Tags: r, ggplot2, subscript

I want to subscript letters in a title that includes the word "in" in the title and it's proving to be quite the headache. I've looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334759/subscript-letters-in-ggplot-axis-label) and tried to translate it for my purposes but have not had any success.

I want to create a title that says "Growth Rate in SMMAsn" where the "Asn" is subscripted.
If I do the standard quoted title it obviously shows up as is.

When I try to use

```
labs(title=expression(Growth Rate 'in' SMM[Asn]))
```

I get an error:

```
Error: Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?
```

There is also an error indicated by R Studio at that line that says:

```
unexpected token: 'Rate'
unexpected token: 'SMM'
unexpected token: '['
unexpected closing bracket: ']'
unmatched opening bracket: '('
unexpected token: ')'
```

Just to see if I could get the subscripting to work at all, I tried using the expression function for just the word that needed to be subscripted:

`labs(title = expression(SMM[Asn]))`

That worked just fine! I got real excited and thought, since everything after the "Growth" part of the expression gives me some kind of error, I can maybe concatenate the rest of the title and the part that needs subscripting with the expression function:

`labs(title=c("Growth Rate in", (expression(SMM[Asn]))))`

All that does is give me a title that says "Growth Rate in" leaving the part that needed to be subscripted out of the title entirely.

I'm kind of at a loss here. I have no formal training in any language aside from R so I'm concerned it's some basic coding logic thing that I'm missing, but it's exhausting me and I can't figure it out. Any advice on how to ameliorate this situation would be greatly appreciated.

If it helps here is the entire context:

```
ggplot(klett.smm.asn2, aes(x=Strain, y=Generations.hr, fill=Strain))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.7, color="black")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Generations.hr-StDev, ymax=Generations.hr+StDev), width=.1, size = 1)+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(hjust=.5, vjust=1))+
  theme(text=element_text(size=30), 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.position="none",
        axis.title.x = element_blank() )+
  ylab("Generations/hr")+
  #labs(title=expression(Growth Rate 'in' SMM[Asn]))+
  #labs(title = expression(SMM[Asn]))
  labs(title=c("Growth Rate in", (expression(SMM[Asn]))))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#A0A0A0","#45b500", "#00b3f2", "#ff61c7"))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,0.9))+
  geom_text(x = 4, y = 0.9, label = "**", size = 10)+
  geom_text(x = 3, y = 0.88, label = "**", size = 10)+
  geom_text(x = 2, y = 0.84, label = "*", size = 10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title can be a formula with words separated by tildes. Using the built-in `BOD`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(BOD, aes(Time, demand)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = Growth ~ Rate ~ 'in' ~ SMM[Asn])
```

[image: screenshot]