# ggplot2, getting a % symbol in subscript within axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I'm trying to get a % symbol in the axis as subscript. Typically, using expression and square brakets `[]` you can get subscripts. But symbols don't seem to be parsing correctly as I get an error. Does anyone know how to fix or a work around? For instance, what would I do if I want `%` in subscript below:

```
library(tidyverse)
  
iris %>% ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = Species)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = loess) + 
  labs(y = expression(Blah[1*d]*"%"))
```

When the `%` sign is moved in the brackets

```
iris %>% ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = Species)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = loess) + 
  labs(y = expression(Blah[1d%]))
```

the following error message appears:

> Error: unexpected symbol in: "  geom_smooth(method = loess) +
> labs(y = expression(Blah[1d"

Comment: Put your "%" into the square bracket

Comment: Thank you. I have literally been looking everywhere to try and find a solution. Do you know why it doesn't work without the  quotes?

Comment: `%` is used to create operators in R. By itself it isn't a valid symbol and expressions can only contain valid symbols. Also, maybe study `help("plotmath")` if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Possible duplicate post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17334759/680068

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the `%` sign in the square brackets and using quotation marks`""` removes the error message

```
iris %>% ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = Species)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = loess) + 
  labs(y = expression(Blah["1d%"]))
```

and yields this plot:

[image]

Comment: This post is a typo, please vote to close as such.

Comment: This post ins't a typo. In all honesty it isn't very clear as to what you should do to insert symbols in the axes, so I think it is useful and should remain open. I looked (perhaps not very well) for quite some time before posting this.

Comment: @zx8754 I vote to reopen the question as this is not a typo and is reproducible. Moreover I detailed the question so that it is more clear. Please have a look again